# usbmount - folder permissions (root)

Tags: permissions, mount, automount

I have a question related to `usbmount`and the root rights.
I installed `usbmount` on my Ubuntu (18.04.2 LTS) and it mounts various USB-Sticks to the right folder (`/home/user1/USB`) I have specified in the `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` file.

I can open the folder and view the content in the GUI, but I can't open a media file (e.g. watch an .mp4 with VLC). VLC would open but not show anything.

Checking the folder permissions, it seems like the `/home/user1/USB` folder permits 
access from root only. If I want to change the owner of the folder I get an error message.

I also tried the suggestions in [usbmount + samba permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86686/usbmount-samba-permissions), which don't change anything.

Does anyone have any other suggestion how I could access the files?

Here is my `usbmount.conf`:

```
ENABLED=1
MOUNTPOINTS="/home/user1/USB"
FILESYSTEMS="vfat ntfs fuseblk  ext2 ext3 ext4 hfsplus"
MOUNTOPTIONS="sync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime"
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
VERBOSE=no
```

NTFS-formatted sticks also don't get mounted, but I think it's better to focus on the other problem first.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this myself as I do not use usbmount, but I am guessing the variable

```
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
```

needs to be modified.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount/blob/master/usbmount.conf):

```
# Filesystem type specific mount options: This variable contains a space
# separated list of strings, each which the form "-fstype=TYPE,OPTIONS".
#
# If a filesystem with a type listed here is mounted, the corresponding
# options are appended to those specificed in the MOUNTOPTIONS variable.
#
# For example, "-fstype=vfat,gid=floppy,dmask=0007,fmask=0117" would add
# the options "gid=floppy,dmask=0007,fmask=0117" when a vfat filesystem
# is mounted.
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS=""
```

The documentation is perhaps a little bit ambiguous, but it seems to suggest that you should use the following (as an example for the vfat filesystem):

`FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"`

If needed, add more strings of the type "-fstype=xyz, options" to that line for each additional filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did that, but unfortunately I get the exact same result. I tried a reboot, but still the same.
ls -l gives me: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root
In Files, I see the mount-folder with a lock, but I can copy data from it but just not play content from it...
Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After further research I made it work, for reference:

- Clean install the usbmount via a self-compiled .deb-File (Instructions: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/automatically-mount-usb-drives-on.html)
- configure `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` as indicated above, but there was a small error I believe `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS` should be:

  FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0007,fmask=0177"

Hope this helps.
This currently only works for FAT formatted USBs. NTFS-formatted sticks I wasn't able to automount (yet) even though I added the `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS` commands.

Answer (score 0):

For my exFat USB flash drive, I added exfat to the list of supported filesystems:

```
FILESYSTEMS="exfat vfat ext2 ext3 ext4 hfsplus"
```

And liberal permissions:

```
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,users,rw,umask=000 -fstype=exfat,users,rw,umask=000"
```

Which worked after a reboot.